# Find documents including `(+++)` in their file-name using windows search

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-search

I have a folder with a bunch of subfolders.

Some of the sub-folders have `(+++)` in their file-name.

I want to find *just* those folders.

Using `name:"(+++)"` or `name:"+++"` as a search term just returns every item in the folder, and all the sub-folders.

My knee-jerk response here would be "I just need to escape the special characters". However, `name:"\(\+\+\+\)"` and `name:"\+\+\+"` return nothing, and MSDN's ["Advanced Query Syntax"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28VS.85%29.aspx) doc page doesn't even mention how to escape a string (or that the `+` character is a special character, either).

How can I search for files or folders that have what are apparently special characters in their name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filename:~=+++` to find all folders that have +++ in them.

If you want to search for `(+++)` use: `name:~"*(+++)*"`

For future reference ~ means literal string (with some exceptions, like `*`)

Comment: I am doing this in windows explorer. A command line solution will not work here. (I need to do a right-click+drag operation on the selected results)

Comment: Why can't you use powershell?

Comment: Because I have a GUI, and really don't want to learn a whole new command-line system. Also, it's not what I asked in my question.

Comment: Windows has a very sophisticated search system built into the GUI. I should not have to descend to the command line just to search for certain file-names.

Comment: Try the above, should work

Comment: Using `name:~"*(+++)*"` worked. Where the heck is that documented?

Comment: Also, is there a difference between `name:` and `filename:`?

Comment: No idea, sorry.